# What does `ec` mean in `HWaddr ec`?

Tags: networking, ethernet, mac-address, network-interface

When I do `ifconfig` on my laptop I get `HWaddr ec` and than an address, this is next to `eth0`. Note that my IPv4 address only appears next to eth1 so I assume my laptop uses the `eth1` network interface.

I assume my fixed pc uses the `eth0` network interface because when I did `ifconfig` from there it did not display `eth1`, only `eth0`. What is strange though is that the `HWaddr` displayed next to `eth0` from my fixed computer is different from the `HWaddr` next to `eth0` when I do `ifconfig` on my laptop.

Background:

This is on my home network. 
There is a gateway which is connected to dsl. It connects to 1 wireless transceiver device and 2 fixed computers. At the moment of me doing ifconfig one fixed computer was connected to the internet. And one(my laptop) computer was accessing wireless internet.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't just the first two digits of the MAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the **`ec`** you're seeing is actually the first part of your actual MAC address.

This can be somewhat confusing because `ifconfig` lists a lot of the information parameters by separating name and value with a **`:`**. The output for the MAC address differs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`HWaddr` is the [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) address of your network card so it must be different for every network card in the world.

Your laptop has multiple network cards eth0 end eth1 are the referring to those 2 cards (presumably a wired and wireless car)

Comment: I know that HWaddr is the MAC address, but my question was what the `ec` part meant. But anyway, I didn't know that eth0 and eth1 always refer to the network interface controllers of the computer that you `ifconfig` on.